# Passing data from a UIPickerView back to its delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview, delegation

I have a UIPickerView inside a custom tableViewCell (subclassed). I'am able to populate it and get data back from it. More or less.

I have this method I implement in order to get info everytime some of the components changed:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{



    if (self.pickerDelegate !=nil &&[self.pickerDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PickerCellDelegate)]) {


        if ([self.pickerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(somethingOnThePickerIsSelected:selectionArray:)]){


            NSMutableArray *pepe;

            for (int i=0; i<[[self.cellPickerInputDictionary objectForKey:@"components"] count]; i++) {

                NSObject*foo=[[[self.cellPickerInputDictionary objectForKey:@"components"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[self.cellPicker selectedRowInComponent:i]];

                [pepe addObject:foo];

                NSLog (@"foo: %@", foo);

            }

            NSLog (@"pepe: %@", pepe);

          [self.pickerDelegate somethingOnThePickerIsSelected:self selectionArray:pepe];


        }
    }


}
```

I have two components, but in order to make it "universal" (independent of a particular situation) I don't want to hard-write numbers here and there.

In the example shown, I don't understand why the NSLog shows correct for the variable foo but shows null for the NSMutableArray pepe.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Objective-C hint: In `self.pickerDelegate !=nil &&[self.pickerDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PickerCellDelegate)]`, the first check is redundant. Sending a message to `nil` returns `nil`, `0`, `0.0` or `NO`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your pointer. I got this piece of code from a tutorial some time ago and as I checked it, I noticed this also. I've been too lazy to change it. But, you know, one is never too sure...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating your mutable array pepe.

```
NSMutableArray *pepe=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

In fact, you can do that on your init method, and declare pepe as property

Comment: I cannot believe this happened to me. Thanks a lot.